# smooth scroll + auto scroll richtextbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

so I tried to making quick text viewer, but...

After ton of Google search, tried this following code:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
        RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub
```

Still, they didn't scroll.

So I put this code to Form1_load, they scroll to the end instead.

All I want is auto scrolling, repeatedly.

Just like ACiDview actually

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add this :
RichTextBox1.focus()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).